# How to make a banner with swapping images in pure html/css?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a banner image that keeps infinitely swapping to another image every 5 seconds with a dissolve transition between each (with 4 images in collection).. using css only

```
 <div>
 <img src="img1.jpg">
 <img src="img2.jpg">
 <img src="img3.jpg">
 <img src="img4.jpg">
 </div>
```

should I make an animation for each image separately, or use the delay property, I've been trying but nothing seems to achieve what I'm looking for perfectly.

Comment: Just use an infinite CSS animation.

Comment: here is your answer: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

Answer (score 0):

You could put all the images in one row with an image editor (such as Photoshop or GIMP)
The problem with this is you cannot each of the images to a separate web pages (you probably could unless you want lots of more code)
Repeating the images forever will not work in HTML.

Have a look at this page and tell me what you think: http://designshack.net/articles/css/infinitephotobanner/

If you think this answer or any other answers answers your question in the best way, please click the tick on the left (I guess you know this already)

EDIT
This is for scrolling images, have a look at the link aldanux gave you if you do do not want the scrolling: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/